# Error installing uwsgi in virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to install uswgi in a virutal env on linux ubuntu, python 3.5.2
I do

```
pip install uwsgi
```

I got this error

```
Failed building wheel for uwsgi
```

and at the end of the installing logs

```
    *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
[thread 0][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
[thread 1][x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread] plugins/python/pyutils.o
In file included from plugins/python/python_plugin.c:1:0:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from plugins/python/pyutils.c:1:0:
plugins/python/uwsgi_python.h:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

----------------------------------------

Command "/home/ubuntu/envflask/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-wthov1ur/uwsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-quiupta5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/envflask/env/include/site/python3.5/uwsgi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wthov1ur/uwsgi/
```

- Linux 4.4.0-66-generic x86_64
- Python 3.5.2

It is any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Upgrading python to 3.9.7 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 74):

You need to install Python3.5 development files, so run this command:

```
apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

The above command will install Python 3 headers to build uWSGI from source.

Comment: This works! Thanks!! now I have uWSGI installed in my virutal env. But i can not run it with python 3. I run with  `sudo uwsgi --http :80 --wsgi-file main.py --callable app --master --processes 8 --threads 2` and I see this line `Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]`

Comment: Because `sudo` means to run some command as some other user (root by default), you can see  [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/600349/why-sudo-python-and-python-in-terminal-start-two-different-versions-python/600350).

Comment: but if I don't run like sudo, I can not run it using port 80

Comment: @AlvaroB, just install proper python version in virtualenv. `$ virtualenv -p python3.6   .venv` and then `$ . .venv/bin/activate` and  ' $ python --version '  must be  `3.6.x`

Comment: I have migrated to python3.6 and it's wokring fine. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! You saved my time! I installed python3.7-dev as I use python3.7.9.

Answer (score 38):

`apt-get install build-essential python3-dev`

From the uWSGI [documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#installing-uwsgi-with-python-support):

> uWSGI is a (big) C application, so you need a C compiler (like gcc or clang) and the Python development headers.
>   On a Debian-based distro an
>   `apt-get install build-essential python-dev` will be enough.

For Python3, just change that to `python3-dev`.

`$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
$ pip3 freeze
uWSGI==2.0.15`

Answer (score 19):

For anyone with python 3.6 facing the same problem here is the step to solve it :

Get python 3.6 dev tools from this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

Then update your package list with :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install your dev tools with 3.6 version

```
apt-get install build-essential python3.6-dev
```

Activate your virtual environment with and then install uwsgi:

```
pip install uwsgi
```

Comment: it's really useful, even for python 3.11, just replace the version:
```
apt-get install build-essential python3.11-dev
```

Answer (score 7):

Debian have package depending on all supported Python 3 development packages:

```
apt-get install python3-all-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same issue. I solve it by following:

> `sudo apt install libpython3.7-dev`

If your python version is 3.6, then use 3.6 instead of 3.7.
After that install uwsgi using pip:

```
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can use `conda` to install `uwsgi`, but make sure to use `conda-forge` channel:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge uwsgi
```

Answer (score 5):

if you faced with the same problem while installing uwsgi under python3.6
just

```
apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

In my case uwsgi installed via buildout

NOTE: may be you should add valid ppa

Answer (score 2):

You must install `python3-devel` package:

```
$ sudo dnf install python3-devel -y
```

And then install `uwsgi` module:

```
$ pip install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this one, trying to install uwsgi on Unbuntu in Windows Linux Subsystem.
Although it didn't give permission error, I solved it by running:

```
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

For openSUSE (tumbleweed),

1. I deactivated and deleted my venv
2. installed python3-devel via yast2
3. then recreated and activated my venv
4. and `pip install uwsgi`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install uwsgi command, through

```
curl http://uwsgi.it/install | bash -s default /tmp/uwsgi
```

mv /tmp/uwsgi to /usr/local what ever

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when installing uwsgi

```
 ibpython3.7m.a’ generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 8.1.
```

The default Python was 3.7 and I had to use pip3.8 to solve this problem.
However I have another problem. Running

```
sudo uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app
```

generates the following error:

```
uwsgi: invalid option -- 'w'
getopt_long() error
```

I have tried many things, including [modular installation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Install.html)
The main problem is that the default uwsgi folder is /usr/bin/uwsgi but when I install using pip3.8 it is not set to default. I couldn't resolve this problem and I switched to [fastapi and uvicorn](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/).
I'm still interested to find the solution to my problem.

Comment: try  this , 

sudo uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http --plugin python3  --module wsgi:app