# pip install uwsgi gives Error : AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'

Tags: python, uwsgi

System : Windows 10
Python : 3.9.5

I was learning to Deploying a Flask app on Google Cloud.
I was trying to install uwsgi (on my windows system) as shown in [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/a2g9pDleGQk?t=172).

```
pip install uwsgi
```

This error is coming

```
    (flask) D:\projects\websites\googleHostFlaskApp>pip install uwsgi
Collecting uwsgi
  Using cached uWSGI-2.0.19.1.tar.gz (803 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\projects\websites\googlehostflaskapp\env\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-93528com\\uwsgi_9bf2ba795b9549d6a9a0d2dfa78cd774\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-93528com\\uwsgi_9bf2ba795b9549d6a9a0d2dfa78cd774\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-tiy5mnl9'
         cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-93528com\uwsgi_9bf2ba795b9549d6a9a0d2dfa78cd774\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-93528com\uwsgi_9bf2ba795b9549d6a9a0d2dfa78cd774\setup.py", line 3, in <module>     
        import uwsgiconfig as uc
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-93528com\uwsgi_9bf2ba795b9549d6a9a0d2dfa78cd774\uwsgiconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
        uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]
    pi
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/75/45234f7b441c59b1eefd31ba3d1041a7e3c89602af24488e2a22e11e7259/uWSGI-2.0.19.1.tar.gz#sha256=faa85e053c0b1be4d5585b0858d3a511d2cd10201802e8676060fd0a109e5869 (from https://pypi.org/simple/uwsgi/). Command errored 
out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answers i tried :
[For windows :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268566/uwsgi-fails-to-install-on-windows)  I am not sure where we have to place the file given in the answer ?
[For ubuntu :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037637/error-installing-uwsgi-in-virtualenv) I get that i have to add some development library to python, but not able to find the correct one [here](https://pypi.org/search/?q=libpython3.7-dev&o=) to install it in my windows system.

Comment: Where do you intend to install it? Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: windows, as mentioned in the in the question @seraph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing UWSGI wasn't an easy task. @Seraph answer did helped but he missed some points, that i did to finally install UWSGI.

So here is Complete Steps so that you won't have to waste a day on this like me:

1. **Install Cygwin** [*download*](https://www.cygwin.com/)
   *(Cygwin is an open source collection of tools that allows Unix or Linux applications to be compiled and run on a Windows operating system from within a Linux-like interface)*.
   [This youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3wm4Ytho4Q) will help you in the process of downloading Cygwin.
2. **Packages u require** in cygwin :
   gcc-core
   gcc-g++
   libintl-devel
   python3-devel
   python38-devel
   gettext-devel

(if it gives error that it *require c compiler, then gcc-core* will help, if it errors: *-lintl missing, then libintl-devel* helps)

3.After you open the Cygwin app, you can follow the above youtube link, to **successfully run uwsgi on your Windows System.**

Comment: ah thanks for the reminder, i forgot about the gcc part

Comment: yeah it really took too much effort finding about it, as i am new. But thanks mate. @seraph

Comment: already tried it, but not working

Answer (score 1):

To install uWSGI **on Windows**, you need Cygwin.

**Note** that you need to have all dependencies installed, check your Cygwin if it contains the `Devel` category and `python3.6-devel` package.

After installing Cygwin, download the stable release of uWSGI from https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Download.html

Extract the stable release file to any folder you want (such as `/user/Desktop/usgwi/`), then open **Cygwin terminal** and redirect to the uwsgi folder. In this case, we use  `cd /user/Desktop/usgwi/uwsgi-2.0.19`. ****Note that you should use your own path and check the folder name.***

Once you are in the directory, run `python3 setup.py install`

After installing just run `uwsgi --version` to do a quick check.

The rest of information that you needed are in the official documentation.

Comment: I've tried the way you mentioned here, it's not working